# Can't change the layout of alternatives keys show on android keyboard

Tags: java, android

I want to change the default layout which Android uses for show the alternative keys when performs a long-press on a key. Keys have an attribute "android:popupKeyboard" used for define the layout of the alternative key list (which could be a Keyboard reference) but when I use it the Android's default layout still appears. Is possible to change or override this layout?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible without writing your own software keyboard. You'll find a good starting point in [Creating an Input Method.](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/creating-input-method.html)

Comment: We have it done already, and our own design for the whole keyboard aswell. But we'r still having problems with the layout for the alternative key list.

Comment: Are you adjusting android:popupCharacters as well?